# How do I set the tty that GDM spawns on?

Tags: x11, systemd

On my computer (under Arch Linux), GDM is spawning on tty1 while I would like it to spawn on tty7.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly GDM is not using tty1, your X server is. Secondly if your X server is based on xfree86 (like xorg is) you can pass a tty as a command line parameter to your x server.